# How can I mock or stub case classes and extractors in scala?

Tags: scala, lift, scalatest

As an example, I have a simple extractor, `Planex`, that takes apart .plan file strings and puts them back together. I have a few unit tests on it that pretty thoroughly define its behavior. Here's the extractor:

```
object Planex {
  def apply(metadata: String, plan: String) = {
    String.format("%1$sPlan:\n%2$s", metadata, plan)
  }
  def unapply(str: String) = {
    val ixPlanLabel = str indexOf "Plan:"
    when(ixPlanLabel>=0) {
      (str take ixPlanLabel, (str drop (ixPlanLabel+5)).trim)
    }
  }
}
```

I have an `Actor` that uses this.

```
class PlanRepo(env: {
  val jsonFormats: Formats
  val load: () => String
  val planTarget: String => Unit
}) extends Actor {
  implicit val jsonFormats = env.jsonFormats
  def receive = {
    case (metaData: String, plan: Plan) => {
      val s = Planex(metaData,write(plan))
      env.planTarget(s)
    }
    case r: PlanRequest => {
      val Planex(metaData, planStr) = env.load()
      self.channel ! (metaData, read[Plan](planStr))
    }
  }
}
```

From my tests on PlanRepo, I'm able to pass in all of its dependencies, except for `Planex`. For that, I'm still using the concrete extractor object. So my repo test is actually also testing the separately-tested behavior of `Planex`. Is there a way around this?

I have similar problems with a set of nested case classes defining the hierarchy of the json part of this document - I'm having trouble separating them from each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the extractors in a trait, and then just have `Planex` extend that trait instead of implementing them directly.

```
trait PlanexExtractor {
  def apply(metadata: String, plan: String) = {
    String.format("%1$sPlan:\n%2$s", metadata, plan)
  }
  def unapply(str: String) = {
    val ixPlanLabel = str indexOf "Plan:"
    when(ixPlanLabel>=0) {
      (str take ixPlanLabel, (str drop (ixPlanLabel+5)).trim)
    }
  }
}

object Planex extends PlanexExtractor
```

Or, if you prefer, define the interface in the trait, and implement it in the object that extends that trait.

```
trait PlanexAPI {
  def apply(metadata: String, plan: String): String
  def unapply(str: String): Option[String]
  }
}

object Planex extends PlanexAPI {
  def apply(metadata: String, plan: String) = {
    String.format("%1$sPlan:\n%2$s", metadata, plan)
  }
  def unapply(str: String) = {
    val ixPlanLabel = str indexOf "Plan:"
    when(ixPlanLabel>=0) {
      (str take ixPlanLabel, (str drop (ixPlanLabel+5)).trim)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: of course. don't know why I didn't think of this. my confusion on stubbing nested case classes remains, but i'll ask that about that separately.